# While true Breaking Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, while-loop

I've been writing some bash scripts and for some reason, what used to be working code is no longer working. I had not done any changes, but the `while true; do` now breaks my bash script.

Here's part of it. Catting README.txt works flawlessly. The terminal echoes "Test..." correctly, but as soon as it hits "while true" it closes, regardless of the $exec bash that keeps it open after finishing.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat README.txt
echo
echo
sleep 2
echo
echo
echo "Test..."
sleep 3
#The option to read the README.txt file above
while true; do
    read -p "Now is your chance to go back and read.
Or press y/n to continue." yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
$exec bash
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm beginning to think it might be more than a code error.

## UPDATE

After running the script by using "bash -x 111.sh", the error message I receive is

```
+ echo Test...
Test...
+ sleep 3
111.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
111.sh: line 59: `        [Yy]*  ) break;;'
```

How is there an unexpected token or a syntax error when many other sources say this is in fact correct, as well as it working prior to today.

Comment: Huh? What exactly do you expect `$exec bash` to do?

Comment: Has `true` been redefined (e.g. as a function)?

Comment: `$exec`??? not just `exec`? (not leading `$` char, `$` makes a variable named `exec`). Try commenting out that line `#` and put a `sleep 5` before that. Finally, why do you have `break` for both `Y` and `N` responses? Good luck.

Comment: And what happens when you run the script with `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  That shows you what the shell is doing -- whether it is what you expected or not.

Comment: I tried commenting out the line, but to no avail. It works one day, no changes, and crashes the next. bash -x gave me the results of            111.sh: line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
111.sh: line 62: `        [Yy]* ) break;;'

Comment: The line numbers don't match up at all. Looks like you have an unpaired left parenthesis somewhere in the 50-odd lines you are not showing us.

Comment: I just tried again with an old script that I new worked, and it worked on a non-root account, but when it got to the main "while true" statement, it crashed. The script is required to run in a root terminal in order to install updates. Any ideas now?

Comment: The error message can be reproduced by deleting the line `case $yn in`. Did you put a # in front of it, or is it part of the previous line? Do you have a normal \n at the end of the last line?

Comment: Actually Walter, it can't be deleted as that would make all of the options and the second "esac" invalid. I tried this same script a few days later and it works now, but after I edited the final script to include what is in my answer. System bug maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that all of a sudden doesn't work, but I replaced all instances of the while true loop with a read -p.

```
read -p 'Do you have (Program) installed? [y/n]' answer
case "${answer}" in
    [yY]|[yY][eE][sS])
        echo;;
    [nN]|[nN][oO])
    apt-get install (program); echo;;
esac
```

This seems to work much smoother and hasn't failed me as of yet.